# Вставка текста в postgresql

Tags: javascript, html, postgresql

На сайте из `<textarea>` беру текст с переводами строки. В **postgresql** он вставляется в одну строку. Как вставить текст в **бд** с переводами строк из `<textarea>`?

Comment: Все зависит от того, как Вы их сейчас вставляете и проверяете. От этого зависит, где Вы теряете переводы строк и теряете ли Вы их вообще. Может быть, они нормально вставляются, просто Вы их визуально не видите в `postgresql`.

Comment: С помощью js ($("#input").val()) строка вставляется в бд.

Comment: Выражение `$("#input").val( )` всего лишь получает строку и сама по себе никуда ничего не вставляет. И уж тем более JS на клиенте не умеет работать с БД, там как минимум должна быть еще прослойка серверного кода. Для решения интересует полный стек кода от начала до конца включая то, как Вы проверяете. Хотя бы минимальный пример, а то так получается надо догадаться, что там у Вас из тысячи вариантов.

Comment: Значение поля я передаю с помощью HTTP POST в файл.php, в котором идет вставка в бд (insert into table values('Значение поля')

Comment: Ну смотрите, у меня есть развернутый postgres и сервер php. Я собираю минимальный пример http://pastebin.com/AHvfqdeD и у меня все прекрасно работает и pgAdmin показывает переводы строк. Поэтому без минимального примера кода с вашей стороны, который воспроизводил бы проблему, трудно что-то сказать.

Comment: @Влад Никогда не вставляйте текст непосредственно в запрос и тогда никаких проблем с тем какие данные и так же с sql-инъекциями у вас не будет. Всегда используйте подготавливаемые запросы и привязку переменных с данными http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Спасибо, Mike! Воспользуюсь вашим ответом!